# Pressure in a liquid

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

Say i have a bucket of water. I can understand that at any point inside the bucket there will be a force hence a pressure acting downwards, but why is there a pressure acting side ways as well at the same point?
Could anyone give me a intuitive understanding of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we show that pressure is exerted sideways too?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149180/)

Comment: Thank you It did help but it didn't clearly explain. The OP in the link you posted too hasn't got the answer as the check mark hasn't been pressed.

Answer (score 2):

The pressure is due to the random motions of molecules bouncing off the walls. Collisions between molecules create thermal motions in all directions - the net motion is zero, so molecules travel equally in every direction. When they bounce off a surface, the action and reaction force means that pressure is the same in every direction.